# Ways of forming palindromic strings

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages

The following problem was given to us in the recruitment test of InMobi.
Given  a list of strings $\{a_1, a_2,..,a_n\}$, I want to count the number of ways of forming PALINDROMIC string $S=s_1+s_2+..+s_n$, where $s_i$ represents a non-empty sub-sequence of string $a_i$.
As answer can be large to fit in integer bounds, give ans mod $10^9+7$
Example: Given strings $\{zz, a, zz\}$, there are $5$ ways of forming $S$.
$zaz$ can be formed in $4$ ways and $zzazz$ in $1$ way.

Comment: mod $10^9+7$? So this is from which programming competition?

Comment: Is this some online programming contest? The "answer modulo 1000000007" part sounds like how e.g. Project Euler usually formulate their tasks. (And it's hard to imagine why such an answer would be sought for something that's _not_ contest-like).

Comment: It was asked by InMobi in our college.

Comment: So it is homework rather than a contest? Not much better. Who is "InMobi"?

Comment: Homework? No. It was asked in a test yesterday. InMobi is a company that came for recruitments in our college.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all strings and find the number of palindromic subsequences. Now you have to remove those ways in which theres atleast one string that did not participate in palindrome formation. So make all $2^n$ combinations of strings that didn't participate and calculate the number of palindromic subsequences formed by rest of them and keep on subtracting this from answer.
Finding palindromic subsequences in a string is a simple $O(n^2)$ dp. So overall complexity would be $O(2^n.n^2)$

Comment: That sounds like quite a detour. The $O(n^2)$ dynamic-programming approach to counting palindromic subsequences can easily be adapted to exclude ones that skip all symbols in one of the original strings, at a fixed cost of at most a factor of about $4$.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes I got it. $O(n^2)$ would suffice.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it in $O(n^2)$ ?